# saving a records containing a member of type string to a file (Delphi, Windows)

Tags: windows, delphi, file, records, typed

I have a record that looks similar to:

```
type
  TNote = record
    Title : string;
    Note  : string;
    Index : integer;
  end;
```

Simple. The reason I chose to set the variables as string (as opposed to an array of chars) is that I have no idea how long those strings are going to be. They can be 1 char long, 200 or 2000.
Of course when I try to save the record to a type file (file of...) the compiler complains that I have to give a size to string.
Is there a way to overcome this? or a way to save those records to an untyped file and still maintain a sort of searchable way?

Please do not point me to *possible solutions*, if you know the solution please post code.
Thank you

Comment: Sorry my XML answer was a bit dense; I'm actually on the road for two conferences (BASTA! and DelphiLive!).

Basically what you need to do is very simple: create a sample XML file, then start the Delphi XML Data Binding Wizard (available in Delphi since version 6), which will generate a unit for you that has the interfaces and classes mapping XML to Delphi objects, and a few helper functions for reading them from file, creating a new object, etc.

My session (see link in my answer) actually contains most of the details for this process.

Comment: Please also show the edit to my answer: you could store your data in DFM files as well.

Comment: Back online :-) Please make sure you download the samples and slides as well: those ARE readable: the third link under 'Practical XML with Delphi' on this page: http://wiert.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/coderage-4-session-are-replays-online-too/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it with a typed file.  Try something like this, with a TFileStream:

```
type
   TStreamEx = class helper for TStream
   public
      procedure writeString(const data: string);
      function readString: string;
      procedure writeInt(data: integer);
      function readInt: integer;
  end;

function TStreamEx.readString: string;
var
   len: integer;
   iString: UTF8String;
begin
   self.readBuffer(len, 4);
   if len > 0 then
   begin
      setLength(iString, len);
      self.ReadBuffer(iString[1], len);
      result := string(iString);
   end;
end;

procedure TStreamEx.writeString(const data: string);
var
   len: cardinal;
   oString: UTF8String;
begin
   oString := UTF8String(data);
   len := length(oString);
   self.WriteBuffer(len, 4);
   if len > 0 then
      self.WriteBuffer(oString[1], len);
end;

function TStreamEx.readInt: integer;
begin
   self.readBuffer(result, 4);
end;

procedure TStreamEx.writeInt(data: integer);
begin
   self.WriteBuffer(data, 4);
end;

type
  TNote = record
    Title : string;
    Note  : string;
    Index : integer;
    procedure Save(stream: TStream);
  end;

procedure TNote.Save(stream: TStream);
var
   temp: TMemoryStream;
begin
   temp := TMemoryStream.Create;
   try
      temp.writeString(Title);
      temp.writeString(Note);
      temp.writeInt(Index);
      temp.seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      stream.writeInt(temp.size);
      stream.copyFrom(temp, temp.size);
   finally
      temp.Free;
   end;
end;
```

I'll leave the Load procedure to you.  Same basic idea, but it shouldn't need a temp stream.  With the record size in front of each entry, you can read it and know how far to skip if you're looking for a certain record # instead of reading the whole thing.

EDIT:  This was written specifically for versions  of Delphi that use Unicode strings.  On older versions, you could simplify it quite a bit.

Comment: thanks. Let see if I can work this one. I need to change a lot of my code.

Comment: thank you for being so straight. The code pointed me to the right solution.

Answer (score 2):

Why not write this out as XML? See my session "[Practical XML with Delphi](http://wiert.wordpress.com/conferences-seminars-and-other-public-appearances/)" on how to get started with this.

Another possibility would be to make your records into classes descending form TComponent and store/retreive your data in DFM files.

[This Stackoverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281265/delphi-parsing-a-record-of-unknown-structure) shows you how to do that.

--jeroen

PS: Sorry my XML answer was a bit dense; I'm actually on the road for two conferences ([BASTA!](http://it-republik.de/dotnet/basta/) and [DelphiLive! Germany](http://www.delphilive.de/)).

Basically what you need to do is very simple: create a sample XML file, then start the [Delphi XML Data Binding Wizard](http://blog.codebeach.com/2008/08/xml-data-binding-in-delphi.html) (available in Delphi since version 6).

This wizard will generate a unit for you that has the interfaces and classes mapping XML to Delphi objects, and a few helper functions for reading them from file, creating a new object, etc. My session (see the first link above) actually contains most of the details for this process.

The above link is a video demonstrating the usage of the Delphi XML Data Binding Wizard.

Comment: thanks. so now I need to write a full XML parsing function. For such a simple task (saving a string to a file) it's way too much work. unless you have (as I requested) sample code that can do it.

Comment: +1 because Delphi provides an XML interface (msxmldom, XMLDoc) and IMHO it's easier than implementing a custom format.

Comment: if it's so easy please post the code. I don't understand why people don't read the question properly.

Comment: XML is all well for some type of data, but in this case I think it's overkill.

Comment: @wonderer, a) I understanded your question perfectly, b) I post code only if I want to, not because you say so and c) personaly I implement such facilities with a database, like SQLite, because variable length records require more effort to make them efficient.

Comment: @Jeroen Pluimers Thanks for the clarification. I can't see anything on that video, the resolution is so low I can't even make out the text.
This might be a good solution but I just need text and a sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You could work with two different files, one that just stores the strings in some convenient way, the other stores the records with a reference to the strings. That way you will still have a file of records for easy access even though you don't know the size of the actual content.

(Sorry no code.)

Answer (score 0):

```
  TNote = record
    Title : string;
    Note  : string;
    Index : integer;
  end;
```

could be translated as

```
  TNote = record
    Title : string[255];
    Note  : string[255];
    Index : integer;
  end;
```

and use Stream.writebuffer(ANodeVariable, sizeof(TNode), but you said that strings get go over 255 chars in this case IF a string goes over 65535 chars then change WORD to INTEGER

```
type
TNodeHeader=Record
  TitleLen,
  NoteLen: Word;
end;

(* this is for writing a TNode *)
procedure saveNodetoStream(theNode: TNode; AStream: TStream);
var
  header: TNodeHeader;
  pStr: PChar;
begin
  ...
  (* writing to AStream which should be initialized before this *)
  Header.TitleLen := Length(theNode.Title);
  header.NodeLen := Length(theNode.Note);
  AStream.WriteBuffer(Header, sizeof(TNodeHeader);
  (* save strings *)
  PStr := PChar(theNode.Title);
  AStream.writeBuffer(PStr^, Header.TitleLen);
  PStr := PChar(theNode.Note);
  AStream.writebuffer(PStr^, Header.NoteLen);
  (* save index *)
  AStream.writebuffer(theNode.Index, sizeof(Integer));
end;
(* this is for reading a TNode *)
function readNode(AStream: TStream): TNode;
var
  header: THeader
  PStr: PChar;
begin
  AStream.ReadBuffer(Header, sizeof(TNodeHeader);
  SetLength(Result.Title, Header.TitleLen);
  PStr := PChar(Result.Title);
  AStream.ReadBuffer(PStr^, Header.TitleLen);
  SetLength(Result.Note, Header.NoteLen);
  PStr := PChar(Result.Note);
  AStream.ReadBuffer(PStr^, Header.NoteLen);
  AStream.ReadBuffer(REsult.Index, sizeof(Integer)(* 4 bytes *);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the functions [available in this Open Source unit](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/03/12/TDynArray-and-Record-compare/load/save-using-fast-RTTI).

It allows you to serialize any record content into binary, including even dynamic arrays within:

```
type
  TNote = record
    Title : string;
    Note  : string;
    Index : integer;
  end;

var
  aSave: TRawByteString;
  aNote, aNew: TNote;
begin
  // create some content
  aNote.Title := 'Title';
  aNote.Note := 'Note';
  aNote.Index := 10;
  // serialize the content
  aSave := RecordSave(aNote,TypeInfo(TNote));
  // unserialize the content
  RecordLoad(aNew,pointer(aSave),TypeInfo(TNote));
  // check the content
  assert(aNew.Title = 'Title');
  assert(aNew.Note = 'Note');
  assert(aNew.Index = 10);
end;
```